# Create new contract via .call()

Tags: solidity, evm

If `_to`is left empty, and `bytecode` is a new contract, should `_to.call(bytecode)` create a new contract ? Or is it so that when a `_to` address is included in the transaction then the EVM processes it as a non-contract-creating transaction ?

EDIT: I'm trying to create a new contract via a proposal on the http://ethereum.org/dao framework. [This article](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/04/ethereum-in-practice-part-2-how-to-build-a-better-democracy-in-under-a-100-lines-of-code/) said that its possible, but it does not work. So my question is, is it possible to create a new contract using `.call()` ?

[image]

Comment: if _to is empty wouldn't that mean you call a function of an undefined object? This can't work!

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example of how to use the `create` opcode:

```
contract Factory {
    function create(bytes code) returns (address addr){
        assembly {
            addr := create(0,add(code,0x20), mload(code))
            jumpi(invalidJumpLabel,iszero(extcodesize(addr)))
        }
    }
}

contract Adder {
    function add(uint a, uint b) returns (uint){
        return a+b;
    }
}

contract Tester {
    Adder a;

    function Tester(address factory){
        a = Adder(Factory(factory).create(
        hex"606060405234610000575b60ad806100186000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff168063771602f714603c575b6000565b34600057605d60048080359060200190919080359060200190919050506073565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b600081830190505b929150505600a165627a7a723058205d7bec00c6d410f7ea2a3b03112b597bb3ef544439889ecc1294a77b85eab15e0029"
            ));
        if(address(a) == 0) throw;
    }

    function test(uint x, uint y) constant returns (uint){
        return a.add(x,y);
    }
}
```

Just deploy the Factory, pass its address into the Tester, and the Tester will create a new Adder, which it will use to add together integers passed to the `test` function.

The factory will throw if the create failed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this example! Can you please explain how did you obtain that bytecode? I tried compiling the `Adder` contract in Remix but I get slightly different results.

Comment: It's just the straight output of compiling Adder. How is your result different?

Comment: When I add `pragma solidity 0.4.8;` in the beginning and compile with Remix, this is what I get: `606060405234610000575b60ad806100186000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff168063771602f714603c575b6000565b34600057605d60048080359060200190919080359060200190919050506073565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b600081830190505b929150505600a165627a7a72305820e4ea791a28b2087faefce8bb60d7f512153b3d14e381ae6442f5ec19c296c92d0029`

Comment: Oh, the bytecode will change a bit as the compiler changes, but the functionality should be about the same

Comment: Why use "add(code,0x20)"?

Comment: The first 32 bytes encode the length, we want to skip over that

Comment: So the value of "code" should be the memory address of the contract, right? mem[add(code,0x20)..(add(code,0x20)+mload(code))) is the address? Why? add(hex"6060604..",0x20)=?

Comment: The first 32 bytes are the length, so `mload(code)` is `code.length`. This says "use the code starting at `code+32` with length `code.length`

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: You can use the [inline assembly](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=inline#inline-assembly) code `create`**,
(as @Eth pointed out in the comments)

`call()` is made to expose opcode CALL, not to call the opcode `CREATE(s,v,p)`.

From [the documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html):

> All three functions call, delegatecall and callcode are very low-level
>   functions and should only be used as a last resort as they break the
>   type-safety of Solidity.

They are low level functions that implement directly the opcodes. CREATE is not one of them.

**This can be inferred from the following links:**

Here you see create and call opcodes:
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=create

Here you see an explanation of calling a function of an ABI dynamically:
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-does-p-recipient-call-value-p-amount-p-data-do

Comment: Looks like OP can use [inline assembly `create`.](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=create#opcodes)

Comment: I guess I didnt RTFM accurately @eth

Comment: Your answer is correct that .call() can't be used; I just commented on how OP might be able to do what they are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

According to Ethereum Yellow Paper, the OPCODE CALL is used for "message-call into an account". Therefore, essentially, CALL cannot be used directly to deploy a contract.

However, CALL can be used to invoke the public function A of another contract C. If function A further invokes the constructor of C, then this CALL behavior will eventually deploy a new contract, the bytecode of which is exactly the same as C.